# Storing cooked food in ziploc

Tags: food-safety, bread, meat, storage

I am planning to go on an outdoors day trip with no way to heat up food.

Is it safe to heat up a packaged, fully cooked sausage in the early morning (4:00 AM) and wrap it with bread and store it in a plastic ziploc bag for consumption in the afternoon (2:00 pm)? (around 10 hours)

I am ok with eating cold food.

Comment: Several hot sausages might fit in a thermos vacuum flask (a glass Dewar vessel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_flask) I'd fill the thing with boiling water, cap, let sit 10 minutes, pour the water out, and slip my sausage in. Should keep it hot for quite a while. Ziplocs are not guaranteed sterile, and like to come unzipped or develop holes.

Comment: If the sausage is fully cooked maybe you are betting off not even heating it up.

Comment: To add to what @aris said, if you heat it up, it will begin producing a lot of excess moisture that would normally dissipate into the air as steam. If you heat it, wrap it in bread and put it in an airtight bag, you'll likely end up with a cold sausage encased in a gooey doughy mess.

Answer (score -1):

Considering the time of 10 hours in a food without being in the fridge, that can be in danger zone (of bacteria reproduction), so i would recommend you to prepare your lunch a few hours about 2-4 earlier to avoid bacteria reproduction as posible, if the temperature in where you live its cold rather than warm, that can help to maintain a little bit more. if you cant prepare it less late until time of consumption, then it will get some ugly smell in the sausage rather than the bread (if the bread has moisture on it then it will too) tho you can still eat it, but likely or not it will upset your stomach a little.